# bitcoin transaction block height

Tags: bitcoind

Hi I check that in the blockchain.info or blockr.io or other block explorer when checking one transaction ( not my own wallet transaction ) I could see the return value of "block_height" which can be use to count the transaction confirmation using block_count - block_height.

I have my own bitcoin node with -txindex enabled and I add additional txindex=1 in the conf.

But when using "bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction " the parameters was never there.

How do I turn on that ? Or is it a custom made code ?

Bitcoind run under Ubuntu 14.04 x64bit version 0.11.0
I disable the wallet function and install using https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum-server/blob/master/HOWTO.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decoderawtransaction` command just decodes the transaction, that is, it makes the transaction human readable.

Any other (though useful) information which is not related to the raw structure of a transaction is not shown.

If you need further info, you might use `getrawtransaction <tx hash> 1`, which returns both the result of `decoderawtransaction` and some additional info, such as:

```
bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 6263f1db6112a21771bb44f242a282d04313bbda5ed8b517489bd51aa48f7367 1
-> {
"hex" : "010000000...0b00",
"txid" : "6263f1db6112a21771bb44f242a282d04313bbda5ed8b517489bd51aa48f7367",
"version" : 1,
"locktime" : 723863,
"vin" : [
    {...}
],
"vout" : [
    {...}
],
"blockhash" : "0000000084b830792477a0955eee8081e8074071930f7340ff600cc48c4f724f",
"confirmations" : 4,
"time" : 1457383001,
"blocktime" : 1457383001
```

}